# How do I merge the content of SPSS variables from different columns

Tags: spss

I want to create five new variable K1 K2 K3 K4 K5 where the table below will return the content for each in their order of entry as shown on Fig 2

```
SN  ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5 IE1 IE2 IE3 IE4 IE5
1   a   b   c           d   e           
2   b   a       f       c   k
```

Fig 2

```
SN  K1 K2 K3 K4 K5
1   a  b  c  d  e
2   b  a  f  c  k
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible way to do it:

(first recreating your example data to demonstrate on:)

```
data list list/ SN (f1)  ID1 to ID5 IE1 to IE5 (10a1).
begin data
 1,   "a",   "b",   "c", , ,  "d",   "e", , ,     
 2,   "b",   "a", ,  "f", ,   "c",   "k", , , 
end data.
```

This is your example data, now you can run the following syntax, which will yield the results you expected:

```
string K1 to K5 (a1).
vector K=K1 to K5.
compute #x=1.
do repeat id=ID1 to IE5.
    do if id<>"".
        compute K(#x)=id. /* correction made here .
        compute #x=#x+1.
    end if.
end repeat.
```

Comment: I tried this code, but the first compute inside the loop command throws errors.

Comment: you're right - I changed my answer to fit the new version of the question (as edited by OP) but made a mess... should work now.

Comment: I also found out, that the data list procedure reads in "," instead of blanks. So the vector runs out of bounds. But beside of this the code now runs pretty well :-)

Comment: ?? do you get a message about the vector? do you see "," in the data? It all seems to work smoothly here :0

Comment: Yes I get the error message 520 (Index of one vector is missing or is out of bound or is no integer) and yes I see "," in the data ("," is not interpreted as seperator but as data).